# In React, how can I set img src using multiple state properties?

Tags: reactjs, image

In React, I'm trying to set the img src value to a URL retrieved from a list of API objects.  When I only use one property, it works.  Example:

```
return <li key={myObject.id}><img src={myObject.icon.path} alt={myObject.summary} /></li>;
```

However, when I want to concatenate 2 or more properties together to form the url, this won't work.  It simply renders the actual text characters w/ curly-brackets as the img src, which yields a broken image.  How can I fix this?

```
return <li key={myObject.id}><img src='{myObject.icon.path}/someConstantText.{myObject.icon.suffix}' alt={myObject.summary} /></li>;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need string interpolation to concatenate javascript:

```
<img src={`${myObject.icon.path}/someConstantText.${myObject.icon.suffix}`}/>
```

This would be the same as writing:

```
<img src="iconPathName/someConstantText.myObjectIconSuffix"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nm, I was able to do this using ES6 template strings.  I set the following const first:

```
const iconUrl = `${myObject.icon.path}/someConstantText.${myObject.icon.suffix}`;
```

Then I referenced it later like this:

```
return <li key={myObject.id}><img src={iconUrl} alt={myObject.summary} /></li>;
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I figured this out before I saw your answer, but thanks for answering.

Comment: You're welcome! I figured it was only a matter of time before you would solve it yourself. I was in the middle of brushing my teeth as i was writing my own answer XD